# Story/movie about Earth broken into pieces and then reformed by the survivors

Tags: story-identification, movie

Do you know of a movie about Earth being fractured, fissured and finally broken into pieces (by a strange  alien attack). The pieces get into a stable motion around the debris (like the floating mountains of Pandora but bigger). People who are in shelters in some of the pieces generate resources and supplies and build things to get the pieces into one. At the end, they manage to get all the parts back into a near-spherical shape (with the help of gravity). Then they see that this is a new moon of the old.

Comment: It sounds familiar as a role playing game setting, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: @JamesTomasino Reminded me of Earthdawn for some reason

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: This sounds a bit like Jules Verne's [Hector Servadac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_on_a_Comet), except there it turns out that what was thought to be debris, was actually a comet that had grazed the Earth (and had scooped up some people), and Earth itself was still in one piece. And I don't remember a movie being made out of it.

Comment: There's a scene in which the Earth is blown apart in the manner you describe in the beginning of [Titan AE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_A.E.) and then at the end of it, the Titan builds a new planet out of ice rings that gets renamed New Earth.

Comment: New Earth? Planet Bob surely!

Comment: Please, if you can recall, provide where you saw it(ie, TV?) and when; and how old the movie seemed to you at the time.

Comment: Another story in which the Earth is blown apart is "The Forge of God" by Greg Bear.  But Earth's survivors move to Mars instead of trying to put the Earth back together.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forge_of_God

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you talking about [Titan AE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_A.E.)?

> Professor Tucker explains that the Titan was designed to create an Earth-like planet; however, its power cells lack the energy necessary for the process .... The re-energized Titan vaporizes the Drej mothership and **molds the asteroid belt into a new habitable planet**.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a bit like the story to [Septerra Core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septerra_Core%3a_Legacy_of_the_Creator), though this is a computer game. It takes place in a shattered world (Septerra), consisting of seven shells orbiting the core. In the end, the protagonists manage to unify Septerra, and they find three new worlds in their sky.

There is also [Skyland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyland_%28Fictional_World%29), but I don't think they put that together.

Answer (score 2):

There's a very high chance you're thinking of [Skyland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyland).

Comment: Welcome! Why do you say that? (Please check out our [tour].)